# How to use special characters in PHP "S#?!☠✖"

Tags: php, fonts, webfonts, truetype

I have this UTF-8 text

"S#?!☠✖"

I would like to use it in PHP for placing the text in an image.

```
ImageTTFText ($bild, $fontsize, $fontangle, $xcord, $ycord, $text_color, $font, $text);
```

It works well, but for the last two sign I will get an ??.
I tried to convert it with:

```
$newstring = utf8_decode("S#?!☠✖");
```

without any success.

Is there any solution to convert the signs that they are usable in php?

Comment: Probably the gliffs are missing in the font you are using

Comment: What do you want to do with that signs? Maybe using "FontAwesome" will do the trick.

Comment: I changed the font to standart arial.ttf. Do not work.

Comment: the sign is given in the font. I think it has something to do with that the font will UTF-8

Comment: @Steve It’s [glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph).